# Looking for a 7 segment LED Driver

Tags: led

We have been using the Allegro A6276ELWTR-T. This is a 16 channel LED cathode driver with serial data input and current control. Allegro is shutting their fab and discontinuing this part. Any one have suggestions for a good replacement? 8-16 channels would be ideal and the part must be surface mount.

Answer (score 2):

Texas Instruments has a good selection [Here.](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?family=analog&familyId=480&uiTemplateId=NODE_STRY_PGE_T)